# Array to string conversation error after registration form

Tags: php, laravel

I am creating new user, it is going smoothly new user pop up in the DB table but, after sending form. Page is sending me this error.

> ErrorException (E_NOTICE) Array to string conversion

*User Model*

```
protected $table = 'users';

protected $fillable = [
    'name',
    'email',
    'password'
];
```

*Controller*

```
public function register(registerRequest $request)
{
    $request->flash();

    $request['password'] = bcrypt($request->password);

    $user = new User;
    $user->fill($request->all())->save();

    return view('auth.register')->withErrors($request);
}
```

Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: What line is the error occurring on? Also, I would dump out `$request->all()` and see if any of the key values are arrays or objects. I would also looking into using `Hash::make()` instead of `bcrypt()` for password hashing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're passing the request object to the `withErrors` method.

> The withErrors method accepts a validator, a MessageBag, or a PHP  array.

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#manually-creating-validators)